# jQuery Replace Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using jQuery for input filtering, by using `.replace` to check for any unwanted characters.

```
$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\+\W]/gi, "") );
```

Simply, i only want to allow telephone numbers, either `+44` or `0` leading.
When i use http://Regexr.com with the regex, `/[^0-9\+\W]/gi` i can get the results i want. (Anything non-telephone is removed).

My problem is when i use the same regex with jQuery .replace, i get different results. I cannot use leading zeros, nor leading `+`s.

I've setup a JSFiddle to demonstrate: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gawfL44p/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using type of input as `number`  which will not allow those, so use `text` as type instead

> number: HTML5 A control for entering a floating point number. (Taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Attributes))

```js
$("#in").on('input', function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, v) {
    return v.replace(/[^0-9\+\W]/gi, "");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="in" value="help" type="text" />
```

Comment: @Simon. : glad to help

Comment: And now you can type `++++++` in the field.